# iPad Actual pixels for landscape and portrait from > iOS5

Tags: ios, ipad

What are the iPad Actual pixels for landscape and portrait for >iOS5 version?

I have some of the older version info.

1024 × 690  (2048 x 1380) In landscape on iOS 4.3
1024 × 672  (2048 x 1344) In landscape on iOS 5
768  × 946  (1536 x 1892) In portrait on iOS 4.3 
768  × 928  (1536 x 1856) In portrait on iOS 5

We needs this for our responsive background image display where we are creating different image size based on this info.

Comment: You mean in the web browser? An app can control every pixel on screen.

Comment: Please give more information on what you're trying to accomplish. Your intent is unclear.

Comment: The iPad's resolution has nothing to do with the version of iOS.

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/kpeatt/5154680 it does not have dimensions for the newer ios versions thats what i need